# How to increase the threshold of views in list view webpart

Tags: list, xslt-list-view-web-part

I am inserting a list view webpart on a page and selecting a particular view. I am not able to see that view in the drop down, only top 50 views are displaying the drop down. How to make that view visible in the drop down.

Answer (score 2):

Till version of SharePoint 2010, the number of views shown in the drop-down list of views was limited to 50. You can have more than 50 views but to navigate to view 51 you should be knowing the URL. You can give that url in the Advanced section of the web part and the view should be rendered